# LinkButton in nested UserControls not firing Command event

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, user-controls, linkbutton

I have a nested `UserControl` (this control is dynamicall loaded by another `UserControl` that is dynamically loaded by an aspx page inside a MasterPage) in which I would like to use a `LinkButton` and the `OnCommand` Event.

This button must be added to some panel, so I hooked up to the `OnLoad` event of the panel (it needs to be created before events are fired in the lifecycle) :

```
protected void PatentAssignee_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Label label = (Label)sender;

    LinkButton link = new LinkButton();
    link.Text = name;
    link.Command += Link_OnCommand;
    link.CommandArgument = "argument";
    link.ID = "someID";

    label.Controls.Add(link)
}

protected void Link_OnCommand(object sender, CommandEventArgs e) {
    Response.Write(e.CommandArgument);
}
```

But I can't get the Link_OnCommand method to be called. One more thing that my be relevant to this problem : the UserControl is inside an UpdatePanel. I also tried to make the link trigger a full postback :

```
ScriptManager s = (ScriptManager)this.Page.Master.FindControl("__scriptManager");
s.RegisterPostBackControl(link);
```

... but it doesn't change much, the page is fully reloaded but no event is fired.

EDIT: As requested in the comments, here are more details about the nesting :

```
MasterPage
  PlaceHolder
    Page
      UpdatePanel
        UserControl1
          FormView
            PlaceHolder
              UserControl2
                LinkButton
```

This means that `UserControl2` is dynamically loaded.

Comment: Could you maybe include some more detail about the control containing the dynamic link button and where it is nested in the page + master page.

Comment: I added some details... Hope this will helps, but I feel like this will be complicated ;) !

Answer (score 2):

One of your controls in the hierarchy is missing an ID. Set the ID, and the event will fire. This also causes havoc with the AjaxControlToolkit (make sure every extender has an ID or clientside behaviors will often fail to load).

Answer (score 0):

I remember having this problem as well. I didn't find the real problem, but what I did, was hook up the eventhandler in the aspx markup and it worked.

You might also try to hook the eventhandler in some earlier stage of the Page Life Cycle.

Try the PreInit eventhandler.

More info on the Page Life Cycle [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx).

Comment: You mean creating the LinkButton in the aspx instead of on the server side ? How could I do that dynamically, ie with CommandArgument dependent on some data ?

Comment: I'm sorry, my bad :) I thought you were only adding the eventhandler dynamically. I do think dynamically creating controls should be done earlier in the Life Cycle.

Comment: I also tried to do it during the Init... But I think the problem is elsewhere, as I also tried to add a LinkButton manually to my page, and the event wasn't fired either !

Comment: What if you just hook it up to the OnClick event?

Answer (score 0):

for the ajax, I think you can create a reusable class

```
public void registerUCAsyncPostBack(Page page, WebControl webcontrol, UserControl usercontrol){
            Control ControlAjaxNew = null;
            if (webcontrol.GetType() == typeof(LinkButton))
            {
                ControlAjaxNew = (LinkButton)usercontrol.FindControl(webcontrol.ID);
            }
            ScriptManager.GetCurrent(page).RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(ControlAjaxNew);
        }
```